# Unable to do consecutive database inserts

Tags: c#, asp.net, scope-identity

I'm attempting to do 2 SQL inserts consecutively to 2 different tables.

The first table insert works fine. It uses `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to pull the  index number which I then store in the variable `Registree_Index`. This works OK.

I then try to insert `Registree_Index` and some other variables into a second table. This does not write to the second table at all. No error message either.

Initially I thought the error had something to do with reusing my old query and connection string variables, so I created new ones. This has not helped.

Does anyone have thoughts on this? Code follows...

```
private void WriteToDatabase()
{
    Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    string yearstring = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    string twodigityear = yearstring.Substring(yearstring.Length-2);
    string dateAndGuid = twodigityear + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-"  + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "-"  + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "-"  + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + "-" + newGuid;

    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    connection.Open();

    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO registrees (UIDindex, Submission_Number, Homecoming_Form, HC_form, NewRecord, First_Name, Last_Name, Billing_Phone, Addresses_Same, Email) VALUES (@UIDindex, @Submission_Number, @Homecoming_Form, @HC_form, @NewRecord, @First_Name, @Last_Name, @Billing_Phone, @Addresses_Same, @Email)               SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UIDindex", dateAndGuid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submission_Number", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Homecoming_Form", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HC_form", "platform");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRecord", 1);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", First_Name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Last_Name.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Billing_Phone", Phone.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addresses_Same", 1); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);

    ///get index from scope identity
    int Registree_Index = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());



    ///SO FAR EVERYTHING WORKS GREAT! BUT THE REST OF THIS CODE FAILS SOMEHOW.
    connection.Close();
    connection = null;
    insertQuery = null;
    cmd = null;

    string connectionString2 = GetConnectionString();
    SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection();
    connection2.ConnectionString = connectionString2;
    connection2.Open();

    string insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO event_registration (Registree_Index, UIDindex, Submission_Number) VALUES (@Registree_Index, @UIDindex, @Submission_Number)";

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertQuery2, connection2);

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registree_Index", Registree_Index);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UIDindex", dateAndGuid);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submission_Number", 1);

}
```

Comment: You're not executing second sql insert. `cmd.ExecuteScalar`. Also, consider using `using` statements in your code to not worry about `closing` connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

```
private void WriteToDatabase()
    {
        Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        string yearstring = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        string twodigityear = yearstring.Substring(yearstring.Length - 2);
        string dateAndGuid = twodigityear + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + "-" + newGuid;
        int Registree_Index;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO registrees (UIDindex, Submission_Number, Homecoming_Form, HC_form, NewRecord, First_Name, Last_Name, Billing_Phone, Addresses_Same, Email) VALUES (@UIDindex, @Submission_Number, @Homecoming_Form, @HC_form, @NewRecord, @First_Name, @Last_Name, @Billing_Phone, @Addresses_Same, @Email)               SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UIDindex", dateAndGuid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submission_Number", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Homecoming_Form", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HC_form", "platform");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRecord", 1);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", First_Name.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Last_Name.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Billing_Phone", Phone.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addresses_Same", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);

                ///get index from scope identity
                Registree_Index = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }

            string insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO event_registration (Registree_Index, UIDindex, Submission_Number) VALUES (@Registree_Index, @UIDindex, @Submission_Number)";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery2, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registree_Index", Registree_Index);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UIDindex", dateAndGuid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submission_Number", 1);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm going to be writing to still more tables. Is having different variables for command, insert etc. just unnecessary?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anywhere you are calling `cmd2.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: I'm only use ExecuteScalar once to get the initial index in the registrees table. I then place that number into the variable Registree_Index and then insert that into the other table event_registration. Don't need to use ExecuteScalar on that second table.

Comment: NO, you need to use; using `ExecuteScalar` you are instructing your program to run the command against database; else it never executes that command and that's what exactly you are experiencing.

Comment: OK, I  didn't understand that ExecuteScalar wrote to the database. Just found code for it as a means to grab the index. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you never execute `cmd2`. Since `insertQuery2` is only inserting to `event_registration` table, you can execute `cmd2` by calling `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

On a side note, you should consider to use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to make sure that `connection` and `connection2` are closed after the queries are executed. Below is the modified code with [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

```
private void WriteToDatabase()
{
    Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    string yearstring = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    string twodigityear = yearstring.Substring(yearstring.Length-2);
    string dateAndGuid = twodigityear + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-"  + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "-"  + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "-"  + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + "-" + newGuid;

    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO registrees (UIDindex, Submission_Number, Homecoming_Form, HC_form, NewRecord, First_Name, Last_Name, Billing_Phone, Addresses_Same, Email) VALUES (@UIDindex, @Submission_Number, @Homecoming_Form, @HC_form, @NewRecord, @First_Name, @Last_Name, @Billing_Phone, @Addresses_Same, @Email)               SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    int Registree_Index = 0;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UIDindex", dateAndGuid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submission_Number", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Homecoming_Form", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HC_form", "platform");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRecord", 1);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", First_Name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Last_Name.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Billing_Phone", Phone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addresses_Same", 1); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);

            connection.Open();

            ///get index from scope identity
            Registree_Index = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }

    string connectionString2 = GetConnectionString();
    string insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO event_registration (Registree_Index, UIDindex, Submission_Number) VALUES (@Registree_Index, @UIDindex, @Submission_Number)";

    using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertQuery2, connection2))
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registree_Index", Registree_Index);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UIDindex", dateAndGuid);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submission_Number", 1);

            connection2.Open();

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I still don't understand is how my earlier code was able to write to the first table at all. I did not use ExecuteNonQuery for that and yet it still wrote to the table.

Comment: Nevermind. It wrote to the first table because of ExecuteScalar. Got it.